# Error returning json data while setting up Stripe payment gateway. Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json

so I have been struggling with this for a couple of days and need to find a solution. I followed a tutorial on how to setup Stripe payments the code below is where I am getting the error :

```
var buyBtn = document.getElementById('payButton');
var responseContainer = document.getElementById('paymentResponse');

// Create a Checkout Session with the selected product
var createCheckoutSession = function(stripe) {
  return fetch("stripe_charge.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      checkoutSession: 1,
    }),
  }).then(function(result) {
    return result.json(); // JSON PASSED FROM HERE
  });
};

// Handle any errors returned from Checkout
var handleResult = function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    responseContainer.innerHTML = '<p>' + result.error.message + '</p>';
  }
  buyBtn.disabled = false;
  buyBtn.textContent = 'Buy Now';
};

// Specify Stripe publishable key to initialize Stripe.js
var stripe = Stripe('<?php echo STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY; ?>');

buyBtn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  buyBtn.disabled = true;
  buyBtn.textContent = 'Please wait...';


  createCheckoutSession().then(function(data) { // TO HERE - ERROR IS HERE
    if (data.sessionId) {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: data.sessionId,
      }).then(handleResult);
    } else {
      handleResult(data);
    }
  });
});
```

So you can see above where I am trying to return the json and where I am receiving it. I have double checked the value that is being returned and it is as followed:

[json result being returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvMKB.png)

and here is the error I am getting :

```
checkout.php:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

From what I can see it seems that somewhere in the return of the data.json(). The data is being changed so that it is not accepted later in the code.
If anyone could help with this or shine some more light on the situation I would greatly appreciate it. I've had a look online loads and can't seem to find anything other than a HTML file is being passed through instead. The issue is that I don't know HOW this is happening even when looking through the debug.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a result, yes, but it is not JSON. Your `stripe_charge.php` request is almost certainly returning an HTML page instead of the JSON you expect. The error is happening when you try to `return result.json()`. You need to check your network responses and debug your server code.

See here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1239019/Unexpected-token-in-JSON-at-position

Answer (score 0):

It may be cause because you have put your code in a custom folder.
It works for me by just removing the "/" in `fetch("/create-checkout-session.php", {method: "POST",})`
in the checkout.html.